# Java - Package woes

Tags: java

I'm not new to Java but I never learned Packages. Anyways, let's say I create a folder called `maina`.

I put in file `main.java` in folder `maina`:

```
package maina;

import other.Dice;

public class main
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        System.out.println(Dice.test);
    }
}
```

Then I create a new folder called `other` inside the folder `maina`. In folder `other` I put file `Dice.java`:

```
package other;

public class Dice
{

public Dice() {

        String test = "Testing!";
    }

}
```

OK, now `Dice.java` compiles fine. 
However when I compile `main.java` I get this error:

```
C:\Users\tekaffi\Documents\ask\maina\main.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable test
location: class other.Dice
        System.out.println(Dice.test);
                               ^
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the error I get when I compile:

```
C:\Users\wekaffi\Documents\ask\maina\myMain.java:3: package maina.other does not exist
import maina.other.Dice;
                  ^
C:\Users\wekaffi\Documents\ask\maina\myMain.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Dice
location: class maina.myMain
        Dice myDice = new Dice();
        ^
C:\Users\wekaffi\Documents\ask\maina\myMain.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Dice
location: class maina.myMain
        Dice myDice = new Dice();
                          ^
3 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Honestly people should read the whole post before answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with packages.

Your code is seriously messed up, you're trying to call a "test" member on the "Dice" class but you haven't created that member. besides that, you **can't** have a class named "main" and then have a static main method in it beacuse the compiler will think the main method is the **constructor** you need to rename your class to something else.

For your code to work your Dice class needs to look like this:

```
package maina.other;

public class Dice
{

public String test;

public Dice() {

        this.test = "Testing!";
    }

}
```

And for the print to work you need to create a new instance of Dice **before you print**
Either that or you make Dice static. So your main needs to be renamed to myMain and then the class should look like this:

```
package maina;

import maina.other.Dice;

public class myMain
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        Dice myDice = new Dice();
        System.out.println(myDice.test);
    }
}
```

If you're placing stuff where you said you are, it should work fine package-wise

Comment: Running that gives me...`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: other/Dice
        at maina.main.main(main.java:13)` They both compile, though.

Comment: @Jahkr please scrap all the other suggestions given to you (besides this one and mine as well, they are the same). Thats likely your issue; they told you to change one thing, which you didn't modify in all of your other files. So its easier just to leave things as they are, it doesn't really matter at all. This code fixes the issue; however the other "solutions" you implemented gave you new ones.

Comment: Yes, yes, I'm trying mathpic. Thank you.

Comment: Hm, it actually looks like the foldering matters, I was under the assumption that it doesn't. That runtime error may also be caused by classpath missettings though. Dunno.

Comment: @Jahkr are "other" and "maina" at the same folder lever?

Comment: Maina is folder where only `main.java` is. `other` is a folder INSIDE `maina` where `Dice.java` is. I though I clearly explained that. :S

Comment: @Jahkr see my edits to the code above. Your class can't be called "main" and have a static main method because the compiler will think that is the constructor and constructors can't be static. you need to change the class name to myMain

Comment: OOh, looks great juandg. However, when I run it (it compiles fine), I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: other/Dice
        at maina.myMain.main(myMain.java:13)`

Comment: Something is jacked up in your set-up @Jahkr, I'm running it on my machine and I get: **Hello world!
Testing!** on the console

Comment: It's most likely my CLASSPATH.

Comment: @Jahkr Code had a small typo, can you try it out again ;-)

Comment: Oh, I see what you did. Sadly, It still gives me error. I edit main question and put the error on bottom. :|

Comment: Something else must be wrong with your system, it works like a charm for me

Comment: I'm running Windows Vista. 64-bit. Maybe Vista just sucks.

Answer (score 2):

Your Dice class must have a package declaration like so

```
package maina.other;
```

Your main class should import Dice like so

```
import maina.other.*;
```

Comment: C:\Users\wekaffi\Documents\ask\maina\main.java:3: package maina.other does not exist
import maina.other.*;

Comment: There were other issues with the code but as far as packages you were right @Kal

Answer (score 1):

It'd be package maina.other, if it is in /maina/other

Answer (score 1):

`Dice` needs a `public static string test`. The current test is a non-static local variable to the constructor. Or you can make `test` non-static and then have the constructor set the `test` member and then do `new Dice().test` in the `main.java`

And the package name doesn't matter, foldering is only a convention and is IIRC ignored by the compiler. So thats not the issue here!

Answer (score 0):

When you put package 'other' inside of 'maina' the new package is

```
package maina.other;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package maina.other;
```

As a side note, if you're using an IDE like Eclipse, you don't have to make the directories manually - it does it for you.  Also navigating your packages with the package viewer is easy.

Answer (score 0):

This one is tough to explain, and you've mentioned that you're new to Java, so please don't let me confuse you.

The package of a top-level type, such as `main` or `Dice` is whatever is listed in the package declaration. The package for `Dice` could just be `other`, even though the corresponding directory is nested inside the directory that corresponds to package `amain`.

The key is resource discovery when compiling and running. When you compile, you can specify a sourcepath and a classpath that helps the compiler resolve dependencies. Likewise, when you run, you can specify a classpath that helps the JVM resolve dependencies. There is no restriction that root packages not be nested inside one another. So, both `amain` and `other` could be root packages, like so:

```
% cd <directory-that-contains-amain>
% javac -sourcepath .:amain amain/main.java amain/other/Dice.java
% java -classpath .:amain amain.main
```

This is considered abnormal (and consequently poor) practice, however. You shouldn't do it, but you could.